# D2XX Sample for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

Can anyone give me a step by step instruction on how to try the **D2XX Sample** on this one:
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_134_FTDI_Android_D2XX_Driver.pdf
im having troubles trying it on my device. as per requirement. my device is already rooted and i have also ndk-build the files but its showing force close when i ran the project.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps you need to take in order to run the sample demo.

1. install the sample application on your android device.
2. connect your device via adb.
3. access your device using adb shell.
4. type cd /dev/bus/usb
5. then type ls
6. you should see directories such as 001 and 002.
7. go to each directory e.g., cd 001 .
8. then use the following command to give your application access to usb:

   chmod 666 *
9. start your application and it should now detect your ftdi device and you would be able to transmit and receive data.

Install the application on your android box.